# Cannot connect the wallet with @walletconnect/react-native-dapp

Tags: react-native, wallet-connect

I setup wallet connect following the docs https://docs.walletconnect.com/1.0/quick-start/dapps/react-native , it working , but linking to metamask or other wallet , not show [image] end this is my code :

```js
export default function WalletConnectExperience() {
  const connector = useWalletConnect();
  console.log(connector.connected);
  const connectWallet = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log(connector.connect())
    return connector.connect();
  }, [connector]);

  const killSession = React.useCallback(() => {
    return connector.killSession();
  }, [connector]);

  return (
    <>
      {!connector.connected ? (
        <Button onPress={(connectWallet)} label="Connect a wallet" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Text>{shortenAddress(connector.accounts[0])}</Text>
          <Button onPress={killSession} label="Log out" />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

, note when i click button connect :  [image] I think , i do something wrong , please help me ! thanks you very much